# Shebang line C. How does it work?

Tags: unix, awk, shebang

I was reading the Advanced Programming in UNIX and stumbled upon this example. What is the shebang line doing here? Here's the top part of the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN   {
    printf("#include \"apue.h\"\n")
    printf("#include <errno.h>\n")
    printf("\n")
    printf("static void pr_sysconf(char *, int);\n")
    printf("static void pr_pathconf(char *, char *, int);\n")
    printf("\n")
    printf("int\n")
    printf("main(int argc, char *argv[])\n")
    printf("{\n")
    printf("\tif (argc != 2)\n")
    printf("\t\terr_quit(\"usage: a.out <dirname>\");\n\n")
    FS="\t+"
    while (getline <"sysopt.sym" > 0) {
        printf("#ifdef %s\n", $1)
        printf("\tprintf(\"%s is defined (val is %%ld)\\n\", (long)%s+0);\n", $1, $1)
        printf("#else\n")
        printf("\tprintf(\"%s is undefined\\n\");\n", $1)
        printf("#endif\n")
        printf("#ifdef %s\n", $2)
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [c]?  It looks like it emits some c-code, but is otherwise not related.

Comment: It means that this file is intended to be an executable command, to be executed (interpreted) by the program `/usr/bin/awk`.  (That's what the `#!` line always means.)

Answer (score 3):

The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line is (on Linux and most Unixes) understood by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). However, POSIX don't specify anything about it. Your script should be run by e.g. [GNU `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk), assuming that script is an executable file (and you probably want it to be accessible from your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))).

So when something (probably your Unix shell, but could be something else) is executing with `execve` that script, the `/usr/bin/awk` program gets executed. You are betting that this `awk` program is some implementation of [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)

Comment: To be pedantic, it's not necessarily going to be run by GNU awk, just whatever awk implementation you have installed in `/usr/bin/awk`.

Comment: That is why I wrote `e.g.` GNU awk

Answer (score 1):

The OS's routines for executing a file look for the two characters `#!` at the start of a file, and if present, instead of directly loading the file as a binary executable, they call the executable file referenced by the rest of that line, along with any command line argument therein, then the original file as a final argument.

That's quite an involved description; a couple of examples make it clearer:

If `myFile` contains:

```
#!/bin/echo My path is
```

... and we make it executable:

```
$ chmod +x myFile
```

... then when we run it, we get:

```
$ ./myFile
My path is /home/slim/myFile
```

Or if we change its contents to:

```
#!/bin/cat
Hello
world
```

Then when we run it, it prints itself ...

```
$ ./myFile
#!/bin/cat
Hello
world
```

This is generally useful when command it invokes is an interpreter which can work with the contents, and itself ignores the shebang. Of course in many languages `#` denotes a comment, so we get this for free:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/bin/awk -f
```

So essentially it arranges matters such that running `myFile` directly, is equivalent to running `awk -f myFile`.